# Spring 3 - Testing a controller @ModelAttribute method

Tags: unit-testing, spring-mvc

I am trying to test a controller with this method:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/export-csv")    
public ModelAndView exportCSV(@ModelAttribute("gsscModel") GsscModel gsscModel) {
```

And I would like to know how can I create a unit testing for testing this. At the moment I am using:

```
    MockHttpServletRequest request = new MockHttpServletRequest();
    request.setRequestURI("/support/export-csv");
    //request.setMethod("GET");
    new AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter().handle(request, 
            new MockHttpServletResponse(), this.controller);
```

However I always get the following error:

> org.springframework.web.HttpSessionRequiredException: Session attribute 'gsscModel' required - not found in session

I've been trying to find info about this on the documentation, but haven't found anything.

Thanks

Comment: Why is your unit test using `AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter`, instead of just calling your method directly?

Comment: Because this method is returning a specific view and I wanted to test the behaviour on the view method: protected void renderMergedOutputModel(Map<String, Object> model,HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
   throws Exception;

Comment: So why not invoke `exportCSV` directly from your unit test, and test the `ModelAndView` that it returns?  Why use `AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter`?

Comment: uhm, I haven't thought about that to be honest. I am quite new to spring mvc so still have a lot to learn. I will try that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To re-iterate my comments, I suggest that you're not unit testing your code properly. One of the benefits of the Spring 3 annotation approach is that it makes unit testing considerably easier, since there's generally no need to mess about with mock request and response objects.

In your case, your unit test can invoke the `exportCSV` method directly, and handle the returned `ModelAndView` appropriately. There's really no need to use infrastructure classes like `AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter` to invoke the method for you, that just complicates things.

Comment: If I wanted to do an integration testing instead of unit testing, how should I appropiately test the @ModelAttribute?

Comment: @tsunade21: `@ModelAttribute` assumes the object is already present in the session, so you'd need to set up your session before calling the method.

Comment: I assume you do that using MockHttpSession. Thanks a lot @skaffman, it really help me out.

Comment: @tsunade21 Yes, `MockHttpSession` is useful for that.

Comment: For the sake of clarity: `@ModelAttribute` doesn't assume that, it looks like there is a `@SessionAttribute` at class level.